# Windows Cannot View Domain Location

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

I used to manage two domain controllers when the primary DC which handled all domain roles, DNS and DHCP service went down. So I configured DHCP and DNS on the other domain controller. The problem is the following:

All PC that are already joined to the domain cannot see the domain. For example when I want to give permission to a shared folder in windows xp I could only give local users permission, I cannot see any other locations other than the local PC it self where I used to view the domain and select domain users before.

I think this problem has to do with the DNS, I am not sure if I configure it correctly as if even DHCP clients are not updating the DNS directory at all.

I am running Windows 2003 Server Standard R2. Please help!

thank you.

EDIT: I am currently running only one domain controller.

```
DC Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DC2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : GOLDEN.AE
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : GOLDEN.AE

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : HP NC7761 Gigabit Server Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-16-35-C2-36-F1
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.54
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.70
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.54
```

---

```
PC Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : MyWorkSpace
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : GOLDEN.AE
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : GOLDEN.AE

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8139 Family PCI Fast Ethernet
NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-11-2F-70-3A-69
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.57
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.70
```

### DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.54

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>DCDIAG

Domain Controller Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
   Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DC2
      Starting test: Connectivity
         The host 0629e11f-c68e-4fbd-acbd-a4f99f47d67e._msdcs.GOLDEN.AE could
not be resolved to an
         IP address.  Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc
         Although the Guid DNS name
         (0629e11f-c68e-4fbd-acbd-a4f99f47d67e._msdcs.GOLDEN.AE) couldn't be
         resolved, the server name (DC2.GOLDEN.AE) resolved to the IP
         address (192.168.0.54) and was pingable.  Check that the IP address is
         registered correctly with the DNS server.
         ......................... DC2 failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\DC2
      Skipping all tests, because server DC2 is
      not responding to directory service requests

   Running partition tests on : Schema
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Schema passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Schema passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : Configuration
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... Configuration passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... Configuration passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running partition tests on : ALGHAITH
      Starting test: CrossRefValidation
         ......................... ALGHAITH passed test CrossRefValidation
      Starting test: CheckSDRefDom
         ......................... ALGHAITH passed test CheckSDRefDom

   Running enterprise tests on : ALGHAITH.AE
      Starting test: Intersite
         ......................... ALGHAITH.AE passed test Intersite
      Starting test: FsmoCheck
         ......................... ALGHAITH.AE passed test FsmoCheck
```

UPDATE:

I am getting DNS Event ID: 4521 now!

Comment: If you want to add enough diagnostic information to provide a better theory about the cause, give full output of ipconfig /all and dcdiag from each DC, and ipconfig /all from the affected client.

Comment: wait, what? how can you have "the other DC" if there is only one DC?

Comment: the problem is as I said. The DC is getting DNS from itself. (As shown in your ipconfig for DC2; IP and DNS server both have same value). DC diag shows, in the very first test, that the DC2 cannot look up one of its critical _msdcs records. Solution: 1) Get DNS working properly on DC2. 2) run ipconfig /flushdns on DC2 3) run ipconfig /registerdns on DC2. 4) repeat steps 2 and 3 on all affected client machines.

Comment: Still, DNS not updating at all. I am getting the following DNS Event ID: 4521.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make [backup](http://www.petri.co.il/backup-windows-server-2003-active-directory.htm) of Active Directory.
2. Make [backup](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2005/07/05/dns-backups-without-the-baggage.aspx) of "GOLDEN.AE" DNS zone.
3. Reinstall "GOLDEN.AE" DNS zone.
4. Restart netlogon service on DC2.

IMHO

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely right - DNS, the glue that binds AD, is broken. Without quite a bit more diagnostic information, it's tough to tell.

What are the DNS settings in the NIC on the "primary DC"? If it is pointing to itself (as best practices say it should), then it is currently registering its various important DNS records with a currently nonfunctional DNS server.

Your best bet would be to get DNS working properly on that "primary DC," then make sure it's properly replicating to thoe other DC. I'd also suggest running DCDIAG on both DCs, and working to make sure all tests pass.

In the short run you *may* get some relief by running `ipconfig /flushdns` followed by `ipconfig /registerdns` on each DC or problem client.

(I have been putting "primary DC" in quotes because I don't want to perpetuate the misunderstanding that AD still has the old NT4-style PDC/BDC distinction.)

Comment: I added ipconfig and Domain Controller Diagnosis. HALP ME!

Answer (score 1):

You shuld have had the DNS service ruuning on both Dc's however to recreate follow teh following article. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q294328&sd=RMVP

Comment: This applies to Windows 2000 Server only. I could not find a similar artical for 2003 :( any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It takes more than /registerdns for a domain controller to update all the underscored records in DNS; you must stop and restart the NETLOGON service. /registerdns just does a computer's A and PTR records. Perhaps do that, then check the zone to see if it looks ok on DNS on DC2.

I assume you changed your workstation's DNS to DC2.

Comment: I should restart netlogon service on the workstations or server?

Comment: Just the domain controllers.